# ¿como puedo abrir archivos .dat y .idx?

Tags: php, sql, rodbc

¿Como puedo abrir archivos y tablas con extensiones `.DAT` y `.IDX` utilizando php?

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web y necesito extraer datos de una base de datos creada por otro programa pero no he podido hacerlo, los archivos de las tablas se guardan en archivos con extensión `dat` y `idx`, aqui les dejo el script que utilizo para tratar de conectar pero no me da error si no que se queda cargando por favor si me pueden ayudar

```
<?php
   $db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver}; ConnectionType=Local; CatalogName=C:\direcciondelacarpetadondeseguardanlastablas\Data;","","");

   $res = odbc_exec($db,"SELECT * FROM customers");
   echo odbc_num_rows($res)." rows found";

   while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
      print_r($row);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código que mencionas, también coloca el error que te presenta ese código.

Comment: Hola, PHP cuenta con varias opciones para consultar varios tipos de bd. Si seria bueno saber  que motor de bd lo creo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno realmente no comprendo bien tu pregunta, lo que muestras en tu código es la conexión a una fuente de datos, en este caso a DBISAM, y en ningún lado veo que abres los archivos .dat o .idx que mencionas.

Dependiendo de como se guardaron los datos en el archivo .dat puedes leerlos a través de la función **fread**.

```
<?php
$fr   = fopen('/path/to/myfile.dat', 'r');
$data = fread($fr, 1024);
fclose($fr);
?>
```

Puedes visitar este link para más información: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/12/12/php_foundations.html

O revisar esta pregunta en stackoverflow en ingles.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586127/reading-a-dat-file-as-rb-read-binary